# Is it possible to have "closed" as the default channel entry status

Tags: status

This seems to be an easy thing, but I cannot find a way in EE where you can select which of the statuses in the status group should be the default status. Am I missing something?

What I want to do is have new channel entries default to status of "closed" and only be "open" once the administrator explicitly sets it to "open". I know that if you do not set a specific status group to a channel, entries will default to closed for non-superadmins, but this is not an option, because we are using a custom status group with more statuses than just "open" and "closed". Does anyone know whether it is possible to set the default status to "closed"?

Answer (score 1):

In Admin->Channels, click "Edit preferences" on the channel you want to change. There's an option in there for the default entry status.

Comment: ah legend! Thanks for the quick response. Knew it must have been something silly that I was missing.